# Only One result per server

Tags: powershell

Hi I have been struggling to solve it.

No matter how many true results exist, I get only 1 folder name and 1 server on the email report.
I reckon I missed something with Foreach.
manually verified each server have at least 5,6 folder where last write time or creation is less then 10 hours, but email report would only show 1 server and 1 folder

```
$emailto    =''
$emailFrom  =""
$smtpserver =''
$Thistime = [datetime]::Today.AddHours(-10)
$ServerList = 'Server1','Server2'
$Result     = @()
Foreach($ServerName in $ServerList)
{
    $check = Get-ChildItem \\$ServerName\c$\inetpub\logs\LogFiles -Recurse  -Filter *.log 
    if(-not($check.CreationTime.Date -gt $Thistime))
{
$status  ='LogsMissing'
}
    Else{}
    
    $Result+= New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    
        ServerName  =    $ServerName
        Folder      =    $($check.fullname).split('\')[-2]
        Status      =    'LogsMissing'
    
    }
}

if($Result -ne $null)
{
    $HTML = '<style type="text/css">
    #Header{font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;}
    #Header td, #Header th {font-size:14px;border:1px solid #FFF;padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;text-align:center;}
    #Header th {font-size:14px;text-align:center;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:4px;background-color:#A7C942;color:#fff;}
    #Header tr.alt td {color:#000;background-color:#EAF2D3;}
    </Style>'

    $HTML += "<HTML><BODY><Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 id=Header>
        <TR>
            <TH><B>ServerName</B></TH>
            <TH><B>Folder</B></TH>
            <TH><B>Status</B></TH>
        </TR>"
         Foreach($Entry in $Result)
         {
        
            $HTML += "<TR bgColor=Red>"
        
        $HTML += "
    <TD>$($Entry.ServerName)</TD>
    <TD>$($Entry.Folder)</TD>
     <TD>$($Entry.Status)</TD>
                        
    </TR>"
    }
    $HTML += "</Table></BODY></HTML>"
    }

$MailMessage   = @{ 
    To         = $emailto 
    From       = $emailFrom 
    Subject    = "IIS logs Creation Status" 
    Body       = $HTML|Out-String
    Smtpserver = $smtpserver 
}
Send-MailMessage @MailMessage -BodyAsHtml
```

Comment: First of all, you need to double-quote the path for Get-ChildItem: `"\\$ServerName\c$\inetpub\logs\LogFiles"`, but also, this can return an **array** of FileInfo objects, but later you treat it as a single file path from which you take the foldername, where you should be looping through the FileInfo objects. Then, your output object has `Status = 'LogsMissing'` hardcoded..

Answer (score 0):

Note exactly sure what your desired results here is or what the source data looks like, but it sounds like you want to enumerate (1) each server and (2) a list of folders.
Your main logic for enumeration a.t.m is the ForEach loop that you process on the list of servers. Thus your ForEach loop will only process twice (server1 and then server2).

If you want to process per server, per folder you will require two ForEach Loops.

Example:

- Get list of servers and perform a ForEach
- Within each server ForEach, get a list of folders and do another ForEach

I hope I understood correctly. If not, give some more context of what you are trying to achieve and maybe a layout of the server/folders.

Comment: That does'nt helps

Comment: Hello @JonDrew - If you can provide a little more context on the structure of the files and your objective I can try to assist further if you are still struggling.

Comment: I am trying to monitor if files not create in X hours ie. IIS logs if not created in last X hours trigger alert, we can schedule it No problem,